# How can I fix the Oracle syntax of this update by the result of a select in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle-10g, syntax

I have a problem with an update statement, that I developed under 11g, when running under 10g.

I reduced the problem to:

```
Create table test (
   col1 number(10)
);

insert into test values (1);

update test set col1 = (select 1  from DUAL ) + 1;

select * from test;
```

When executing on Oracle 10, I get the following error:

```
update test set col1 = (select 1  from DUAL ) + 1
Error at line 1
ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet
```

Any ideas, how I can modify the statement to run under 10g?
I want to use a single statement.

Comment: I guess you mean update test set col1 = 1 + (select 1 from DUAL );

Comment: I added my workaround to the answer I gave, but I'm not sure you should accept it quite yet.  I'd hold out a bit longer to see if someone can post an Oracle bug on it or at least a better explanation of the behavior.

Comment: OK. I'll wait some time.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the Update statement allows this syntax even in 10g, so perhaps this is a bug.  I looked for one on My Oracle Support, but couldn't find one.  Perhaps you should open a SR with Oracle to see what they say.

As a workaround if you re-arrange the statement to have the literal first it will work on both versions.

```
update test set col1 = 1 + (select 1 from DUAL );
```

Another workaround is to wrap the function in to_number.  I don't see why either should be necessary.  Updating a column to the results of a compound expression that contains a scalar subquery expression added to a value is supported by the syntax and should work.

Similar behavior found [here](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/databases-oracle-misc/330157-strange-behaviour-scalar-subquery.html) also with no resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following work around:

```
update test set col1 = NVL((select 1  from DUAL ), NULL) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may just be missing a semi-colon after the update statement. Are you running the exact same code on 11g as 10g?

```
update test set col1 = (select 1  from DUAL ) + 1;
```

Comment: I see the same behavior difference using bernd_k's code block.